# Upgrade (Deployment + PVC) to Statefulset using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

We have realised the mistake of using a Deployment with a PVC for our stateful app instead of going with Statefulset. I was wondering how the upgrade would work. How can I point to the old data with the new statefulset ? I am guessing that the old PVC cannot be used by the volumeClaimTemplate ? I have not found anything via Google with my search abilities.

Did anyone else go through this phase ? If you have, what was the process you followed ?

Thanks.

Adding some more details regarding the setup.

1. Currently it is a simple deployment with no replicas. Just 1 deployment and 1 pod.
2. PV+PVC is used to have a persistent volume mounted where we write all of the data.
3. On Helm upgrade, we have a pre-upgrade hook added which mounts the same PV+PVC into the upgrade container and upgrades the data (Modifying XML files etc)

It is simple, but the helm chart is bit too complicated with lots of other noise, but basically the application can be considered as simple as above.

Now, what I am looking for in my next upgrade is a process where I can make the above deployment as a statefulset and also have all the data still usable by the Pod.

Comment: yes, the old PVC cannot be used for the StatefulSet. In my Corp, we deleted the deployment and create the statefulset and pv/pvc for the volumeClaimTemplate.

Comment: @leo Thank you. So you mean to say, you added a claimRef to the PV to point it to the new statefulset pvc ? Would be nice if you could detail further on the recovery as an answer.

Comment: Can you share little bit more details about your pv deployment (some config examples would be great). Should it be shared among all pods in `statefulset` or every pod should get a copy of that data? Is there is any initial data that should be provided to every pod for later use?

Comment: @thomas Thank you. I have added more details.  I have not added any configs because all the helm charts would make it really difficult to stay on focus. Essentially the application is as simple as what I have described. There is only one pod, no replicas involved.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would like to know more details about your PV and PVC. Is it dynamically provisioned or prepared by you/admin in advance? What is the type of the PVC? Is it NFS, Hostpath or some kind of cloud drive?

Comment: @thomas Using hostpath

Answer (score 2):

So, here is what I did. First, let me brief about my test setup:

1. Have a set of deployments running which are having their own PVC+PV for persistence.
2. New release has all of those deployments converted into statefulsets, thus have different PVC.

Problems:

1. You cannot use the PV from earlier deployment because a PV is bound to a single PVC. You can refer to the PV using only that PVC.
2. So another question is, why can't you mount the old PV using it's PVC to new pod and copy that ?
   Well, we cannot do that because, by the time the new pods are started, the old pods are released thereby releasing its associated PVC and PV. In my case I could see the PVC going to 'Terminate' state. It probably could be solved with some kind of Reclaim policy, but I am not sure of that.

Solution:

1. Create the PV and its PVC's manually and apply them. The PVC name should match the name that the statefulset would create which is quite straight forward. The PVC name matching for statefulset is very important, it expects it to be in certain format which you can find online.
2. In your new Helm chart, create a pre-upgrade kubernetes Job. This is pre-upgrade hook of Helm which is run just before the actual upgrade of Helm release.
   So, here you create a container and mount both old and new PV (use the PVC you created manually).
3. Now, this container must run something right to copy the data ? Yeah, for that I created a new configmap and put a script in it which would just copy the data from the old PV to new PV. This configmap is mounted inside the container and the container is made to execute that command.
4. Run the helm upgrade command and see it in action.

A rough example of the K8s pre-upgrade job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-pre-upgrade-job
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace.name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:

      - name: upgrade82-copy
        image: <your-image>
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c", "/scripts/upgrade82.sh"]

        volumeMounts:
        - name: old-data
          mountPath: /usr/old
          readOnly: false

        - name: new-data
          mountPath: /usr/new
          readOnly: false

        - name: scripts
          mountPath: /scripts
          readOnly: false

      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: old-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: old-claim << Needs to be hardcoded to what is running

        - name: new-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: new-data-namespace-app-0 << There is a specific format for statefulset PVC

        - name: scripts
          configMap:
           name: upgrade
           defaultMode: 0755

  backoffLimit: 4
  #activeDeadlineSeconds: 200
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished : 100
```

And "upgrade" above is another Configmap with your copy script.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, we create the pv/pvc at pre-phase for such Statefulset pods. During the upgrade, we delete the old pv/pvc and using the new, delete the old deployments and create headless service also keep some old services for load balancing.
Because pv/pvc only bond once, have to create the new pv.

Comment: Yes..this is what I ended up doing to. Pre create PV and PVCs that the new statefulset would use and copy the data from old pv to new in the pre-upgrade hook

Comment: @Arunmu, since you solved it, could you post more detailed solution? It might help other people facing similar problems.

Comment: @thomas Sure, I have put it as answer. Please let me know if something needs bit more clarity.